# show search results on different component-page with react/MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

I have a MUi autocomplete component inside a top bar, so it is a fixed general bar shown on all pages. My question is, how can I show the results on a different pages?

```
   `<Autocomplete
      fullWidth
      id="free-solo-demo"
      freeSolo
      options={interests.map((option) => option.name)}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} placeholder="Search" />}
      renderOption={renderOption}
    />`
```

Should I pass the props as paramenters?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the autocomplete results on a different page, you will need to pass the state and options as props to the component on that page.

One way to do this is to store the state of the Autocomplete component in a higher-level component, such as the parent component that is responsible for rendering the pages. You can pass the state and options down to the Autocomplete component as props. Then, when the user navigates to a different page, you can pass the same state and options to the Autocomplete component on that page.

Here is an example:

```
// Parent component
function App() {
  const [interests, setInterests] = useState([]);
  const [selectedInterest, setSelectedInterest] = useState("");

  // fetch interests data and set state

  return (
    <div>
      <TopBar interests={interests} selectedInterest={selectedInterest} onInterestChange={setSelectedInterest} />
      // Render other pages and pass interests and selectedInterest as props as needed
    </div>
  );
}

// TopBar component
function TopBar({ interests, selectedInterest, onInterestChange }) {
  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Autocomplete
        fullWidth
        id="free-solo-demo"
        freeSolo
        options={interests.map((option) => option.name)}
        value={selectedInterest}
        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
          onInterestChange(newInputValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} placeholder="Search" />}
        renderOption={renderOption}
      />
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

Comment: oh.. ok, so I can do that in my App.js for example, with all my routes...

<Topbar setInterests ={interests,} />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard /> interests={interests} />
            <Route path="/users" element={<Users />} />

Comment: Why do all your recent answers read like they were generated by ChatGPT?